# onClick to go to next page not working, what's missing in my function?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Can someone help me with this, please? I can't get my head around why my `showNextPage` function doesn't take me to the next page. When `showNextPage` is clicked, it should update the state and return a new array of items, and display the next project in the array. I am getting a new array, but the page is not displaying the next project in the line. I know there is something missing with my function, but I couldn't get past the mental block. Many thanks for the help in advance.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, useParams} from "react-router-dom";

import SingleProject from '../atom/SingleProject'
import ProjectNav from '../atom/ProjectNav'


function PortfolioPage(props) {
  const {projectDb} = props
  const [projects, setProject] = useState(projectDb)
  console.log(projects)

  function showNextPage (item){
    const idx = projects.findIndex(i => i.id === item.id)
    if (idx === -1) {
      return 
    }
    const newItems = [...projects]
    newItems[idx] = {
      ...item,
      id: item.id,
      title: item.title
    }
    setProject(newItems)
  }
  function showPrevPage (){
    console.log('go to prev page')
  }
  return(
    <Router>
        {projects.map((project) => {
          return <Route path={`/projects/${project.id}`} render={(i) => (
              <SingleProject 
                project={project} 
                key={i}
                showNextPage={() => showNextPage(project)} 
                showPrevPage={() => showPrevPage(project)}
                />
          )}/>
        })}
        </div>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default PortfolioPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps me to breakdown the logic of a function to see where I might be missing something. Here's how I break yours down:

```
function showNextPage (item){
    // Go through all of your projects to find the index of the CURRENT project
    const idx = projects.findIndex(i => i.id === item.id)
    // If I don't find it in the projects, EJECT!!
    if (idx === -1) {
      return 
    }
    // Spread my projects in to a new variables so I can manipulate it without touching the original
    const newItems = [...projects]
    // Update the new array variable index (where index is equal to the current project) to equal everything it already has but also overwrite/create the current project id and title keys.
    newItems[idx] = {
      ...item,
      id: item.id,
      title: item.title
    }
    // Set the project state to the new value (which seems to also be the same as the old)
    setProject(newItems)
  }
```

I'm not sure what the purpose of setting these values is, unless they might be changing on the page and you're saving them? Otherwise, your next page function could probably be simplified to something like:

```
const showNextPage = (item) => {
  const idx = projects.findIndex(i => i.id === item.id)
  if (idx === -1) {
      return 
  }

  setProject(projects[idx === projects.length? idx : idx + 1])
};
```

Edit: The reason I added the ternary in the setState function is to make sure you're not trying to call an index value that doesn't exist. In this case, if you're at the end (and didn't have a check somewhere else for it already) then it would just stay on the same page.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I did wonder if the `newItems` was necessary... The ternary makes a lot of sense! Thank you for your help, I'll give it another go.

Answer (score 0):

```
      import {Switch} from 'react-router-dom'

      <Router>
        <Switch>
          {projects.map((project) => {
            return <Route exact path={`/projects/${project.id}`} render={(i) => (
              <SingleProject
                project={project}
                key={i}
                showNextPage={() => showNextPage(project)}
                showPrevPage={() => showPrevPage(project)}
              />
            )} />
          })}
        </Switch>
      </Router >
```

i think mistake is in routings,make this changes in routes and check

Comment: Cheers for your reply. I've figured out what was going on and came up with a simpler solution since posting the question.